# Plymouth splash screen not appearing/delayed in Fedora 25

Tags: linux, boot, splash

I upgraded my laptop from Fedora 24 to 25 a while ago, and ever since the splash screen during boot has acted strange: after selecting the kernel in grub, a black screen with a cursor is displayed. After a while, the tail end of the splash screen shows but the login screen appears shortly afterwards. When resuming from hibernate, the splash never appears at all.

I'd like to get rid of this delay, but information about possible causes and fixes seems impossible to find. I've confirmed that plymouth is being started early in the boot process and is present in the initramdisk. I tried to enable plymouth debugging from the kernel commandline with plymouth:debug, which worked, but didn't write the promised debug file to /var/log/plymouth-debug.log. plymouth-read-write.service starts, which I believe should trigger the writing of that file, but apparently it does not. Setting the file explicitly with plymouth.debug=file:/var/log/plymouth-debug.log also fails. Pressing ESC repeatedly during booting does nothing. Changing the plymouth theme changed the contents of the initrd but didn't affect the delay. I've tried with each of rhgb and splash on the kernel commandline, and both together (by accident!) to no avail. I'm using i915 which is working fine.

Any help with the delay or just with getting the plymouth debug information would also be appreciated.

Comment: Add 'rd.debug' to kernel args and look for more juicy debug info

Comment: did you ever find a fix? I'm seeing the same problem, since Fedora 24 (and in Fedora 25). Both with i915 and now with the open source radeon driver.